# Change URL - Javascript

Tags: javascript, innerhtml, getelementbyid

I am tying to change the `href` link using JavaScript. In my example I would like to change the url path from "linktwo.html" to "problem3.html.

I know that there are probably easier ways of doing this, but this is for practice purposes.

Using my example as below, what am I doing wrong to change the `href`?

HTML:

```
<body onload="changeLink()">
<div id="p">
<h1> <a href="linkone.html"> first link </a></h1>
</div>
<div id ="q">
<a href="linktwo.html"> second link </a>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeLink(){
document.getElementById("q").href.innerHTML="problem3.html";
}
</script>
```

Comment: How do you foresee `.innerHTML` working? Try `.href = "problem3.html";`.

Comment: Just remove `.innerHTML`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option One** :
Change the Java Script as below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeLink(){
document.getElementById("q").href.innerHTML="<a href="problem3.html"> second link </a>";
}
</script>
```

**Option Two** :
change the code as below

***HTML :***

```
<body onload="changeLink()">
<div id="p">
<h1> <a id ="p1" href="linkone.html"> first link </a></h1>
</div>
<div id ="q">
<a id ="q1" href="linktwo.html"> second link </a>
</div>
```

***JAVA SCRIPT :***

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeLink(){
document.getElementById("q1").removeAttribute("href");
document.getElementById("q1").setAttribute("href","problem3.html");
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check following code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function changeLink(){
    document.getElementById("q").href ="problem3.html";
  }
</script>
```

Comment: This won't work because the id is on the `<div>`, not the `<a>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do:

```
<a id="changeurl" href="linktwo.html"> second link </a>
```

Give your anchor an id and then in the script area:

```
 link = document.getElementById('changeurl');
    link.removeAttribute('href');
    link.setAttribute('href','problem3.html');
```

First you get the object. Then you remove the current href attribute. After that you can add a new one! Hope this helps and better answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should put the ID on the link itself, not the containing `div`.

```
<a href="linktwo.html" id="my_link"> second link </a>
```

Then, you should use the `href` property without `innerHTML`.

```
function changeLink(){
    document.getElementById("my_link").href = "problem3.html";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Give an id for the `href`

```
</head>
<body onload="changeLink()">
<div id="p">
<h1> <a href="linkone.html"> first link </a></h1>
</div>
<div id ="secondDiv">
<a href="test.html" id="q"> second link </a>
</div>
```

and remove the innerHTML part from the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function changeLink(){
            document.getElementById("q").href = "problem3.html";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the helpful information!  Further experimenting resulted in me coming up with changing my javascript to this.

```
function changeLink(){
document.getElementById("q").childNodes[1].href="problem3.html";
```

Not sure if this is practical or not but was an added solution to everyones solutions.